# Modify json values from list of maps and save output

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have the following example json that I read in using the play framework.

```
{
  "field_a": "dummy",
  "field_b": "dummy",
  "nest": {
    "nest_a": "dummy",
    "nest_b": 87
  },
  "field_c": null,
  "field_d": null,
  "field_e": "chocolate",
  "field_f": "sugar",
  "array": [
    "dummy entry"
  ],
  "id": "Anything"
}
```

I Then have the following List of Maps that I want to swap out data with which is my **Input**:

```
val substitutionsList: List[mutable.Map[String, String]] = List(
    mutable.Map("field_b" -> "dummy string", "field_d" -> "2016-01-01", "field_f" -> "2011-01-01"),
    mutable.Map("field_b" -> "dummy string", "field_d" -> "2018-01-01", "field_f" -> "2018-01-01"),
    mutable.Map("field_b" -> "dummy string", "field_d" -> "2018-04-01", "field_f" -> "2018-04-01"),
    mutable.Map("field_b" -> "dummy string", "field_d" -> "2016-01-01", "field_f" -> "2016-01-01")
)
```

I am reading in the json as follows:

```
def parseSchemaJson(schemaContent: String) = Json.parse(schemaContent).as[JsObject]
val baseSchemaInput = parseSchemaJson(Source.fromFile("/dummy.json").mkString)
```

I want to iterate over my Input and swap out the values in the json for the values in my map and after each one is done, create a new .json file.

```
private def replaceField(json: JsObject, fieldToReplace: String): Option[String] = (json \ fieldToReplace).asOpt[String]
println(replaceField(baseSchemaInput, "field_a")) //prints dummy
```

I can list out the value in my json using something like this but I have no idea how to swap the value from my list into each respective bit and write out a json file.

**First occurance of the expected output**

```
{
  "field_a": "dummy",
  "field_b": "dummy string",
  "nest": {
    "nest_a": "dummy",
    "nest_b": 87
  },
  "field_c": null,
  "field_d": "2016-01-01",
  "field_e": "chocolate",
  "field_f": "2011-01-01",
  "array": [
    "dummy entry"
  ],
  "id": "Anything"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for the JSON you provide at the beginning?

Comment: @Bentaye I have added an example output for the first occurance of the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following substitution list:

```
val substitutionsList: List[mutable.Map[String, Any]] = List(
  mutable.Map("field_b" -> "dummy string 1", "field_d" -> "2016-01-01", "field_f" -> "2011-01-01"),
  mutable.Map("field_b" -> "dummy string 2", "nest" -> mutable.Map("nest_b" -> "90"))
)
```

Note that the second one updates a nested value. You need to create a nested `Map` to define nested values.

You can define a function to transform a `Map[String, Any]` (`Any` because we can have either a `String` or a `Map` as value) into a `JsObject`. This is a recursive function and will call itself in case the Value is a `Map`

```
def mapToJsObject(map: mutable.Map[String, Any]): JsObject =
  JsObject(map.mapValues {
    case v:String => JsString(v)
    case v:mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[String, Any]] => mapToJsObject(v.asInstanceOf[mutable.Map[String, Any]])
  })
```

Then go through your list of substitutions and deep merge the `JsObject` made from each `Map` with the original `JsObject` using the `deepMerge` function defined on the `JsObject` class. It will merge the nested objects too. [See API here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsObject)

```
val substitutedJsObjects: List[JsObject] = substitutionsList
  .map(mapToJsObject)
  .map(baseSchemaInput.deepMerge)
```

This should give you a list of `JsObjects`, one per Map in your List

You can then write them to file. Here is an example to write one file per json string. Files will be named `0.json`, `1.json`, etc ..

```
def writeToFile(jsObject: JsObject, fileName: String): Unit = {
  println("writing "+fileName)
  val pw = new PrintWriter(new File(fileName))
  pw.write(jsObject.toString())
  pw.close()
}

substitutedJsObjects.zipWithIndex.foreach {
    case (jsObject, index) => {
      val fileName = index.toString + ".json"
      writeToFile(jsObject, fileName)
    }
  }
```

Comment: In my example, the input is `List[mutable.Map[String, String]]` How could we bring that into a `Map[String, String]` to work with what we have above?

Comment: Simply change `Map` by `mutable.Map` in my answer, should work just fine. I edited my answer with `mutable.Map`. I also edited your question with this information.

Comment: Do you perhaps know the best way to write each JsObject out to a .json file?

Comment: @Curious_Bop I added a simple example, you can modify it to customize the name of the files.

Comment: me again, what would my key need to be to change values within nest, e.g nest_a = dummy? I print out all the keys on the jsobject but it only classes nest as a key

Comment: @Curious_Bop Indeed it was not working for nested objects. I changed it to take them into account. Reread the whole answer, I changed stuff a little everywhere. :) Working now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169879/discussion-between-curious-bop-and-bentaye).